# Offline database for native Cordova Applicaition

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, sqlite, cordova-3, cordova-plugins

Recently I was looking at few blogs and couldn't find the solution to my problem. I am trying to achieve following things in native cordova app.

1.Creating native cordova app using visual studio 2013. Got that working
2. Looking to store some data when app is offline. IndexDB, WebSql and local storage is not any option as data can be more than their actual limit.
Therefore cannot use PouchDB and Taffy.
3. Find few things on sqllite but don't know if we can connect to sqllite db file via javascript.

Any help and direction will be really helpful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this plugin for cordova fits your needs:
https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin

Implements Native sqlite dB access without the 5MB that normally limits websql HTML5. Almost all sqlite capabilities are covered.

You can also integrate this plugin with SQLcypher if you have security requirements.

Comment: I already had a look at this plugin. It looks very buggy as there are a lot issues still open but thanks for your reply I will keep an eye on this.

Comment: Not so buggy, I have used this plugin without problems. There are some controlled limitations due to diferences beween IOS and Android implementation of SQLite, not for the missfunction of the plugin itself.

Comment: Do I have to bit careful or consider anything before using this plugin? the reason why I am asking this that I don't want my application to be rejected by app store.

Comment: 1. Phonegap has accepted the plugin (phonegap build), 2. Github Repository shows al least 4 apps that use this plugin, for example https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/get-it-done-tasks/id412823147?mt=8, you can unzip the IPA (if you syncronize itunes with your device is stored in the itunes folder) and check yourself.